# Clojure: why does (into {} '( (1 2) (3 4))) fail?

Tags: clojure

I've understood that Clojure lists and vectors are mostly interchangeable and using one or the other has to do with things like insert order in `conj` or the lack of need to quote in case of vectors.

Why does then

```
(into {} '( (1 2) (3 4)))
```

fail, while

```
(into {} '( [1 2] [3 4]))
```

succeeds?

Comment: @H2CO3 - both vectors and lists are immutable in Clojure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an artifact of how maps are implemented.

Maps are conceptually treated as sequences of `java.util.Map.Entry` elements by many Clojure functions. It happens that there is special case code in [APersistentMap.java](https://code.google.com/p/clojure/source/browse/trunk/src/jvm/clojure/lang/APersistentMap.java) to treat length 2 vectors as a map entry (in APersistentMap.cons), but not for lists.

Arguably there is a reasonable case for giving vectors this special treatment, because they are a convenient form for representing map entry literals in code. So you can write stuff like the following:

```
(conj {} [:a 1])
=> {:a 1}
```